# Join between Streaming data vs Historical Data in spark

Tags: join, apache-spark

Let say I have transaction data and visit data

```
visit
| userId | Visit source | Timestamp |
| A      | google ads   | 1         |
| A      | facebook ads | 2         |

transaction
| userId | total price | timestamp |
| A      | 100         | 248384    |
| B      | 200         | 43298739  |
```

I want to join transaction data and visit data to do sales attribution. I want to do it realtime whenever transaction occurs (streaming).

Is it scalable to do join between one data and very big historical data using join function in spark?
Historical data is visit, since visit can be anytime (e.g. visit is one year before transaction occurs)

Comment: How often is your transaction data updated?

Comment: Transaction data is to be processed in real time. If what you mean is recordwise, it will never be updated (final transaction)

Comment: Sorry yes. Meant updated as in adding records not updated as in modifying records.

Comment: I see. It is adding every second

Comment: And how often is the "visit" data inserted? In real time or in batches?

Comment: Varies between 0-100/s

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? How did you implement the historical data RDD update? I'm developing a very similar application and have exactly the same question

Answer (score 0):

I did join of historical data and streaming data in my project. Here the problem is that you have to cache historical data in RDD and when streaming data comes, you can do join operations. But actually this is a long process.

If you are updating historical data, then you have to keep two copies and use accumulator to work with either copy at once, so it wont affect the the second copy.

For example,

transactionRDD is stream rdd which you are running at some interval.
visitRDD which is historical and you update it once a day.
So you have to maintain two databases for visitRDD. when you are updating one database, transactionRDD can work with cached copy of visitRDD and when visitRDD is updated, you switch to that copy. Actually this is very complicated.

Comment: How can I join JavaPairDStream and JavaPairRDD ? That is batch data real time data

Comment: @sahu You need to use transformToPair function of JavaPairDStream to join JavaPairDStream and JavaPairRDD.

Comment: I got your idea, but the historical data then is not updated in real time, it might be updated periodically but not fast enough.

Comment: Yeah it will be updated periodically according to your batch process.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but lemme share my viewpoint.Today, this can be easily done in Apache Beam. And this job can run on same spark cluster.